# Unable to compile program using boost on Mac

Tags: c++, boost, osx-lion

I recently installed boost 1.48 on my MacOSX 10.7 using MacPorts. While I am able to compiler some examples given in boost documentation, I am failing in this one (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/bimap/example/step_by_step.cpp). Here is the error message:

```
g++  -Wall -I/opt/local/include  -L/opt/local/lib   step_by_step.cpp   -o step_by_step
In file included from /usr/include/machine/_types.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/sys/_types.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/_types.h:27,
                 from /usr/include/unistd.h:71,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/os_defines.h:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/c++config.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cstddef:50,
                 from /opt/local/include/boost/config/select_stdlib_config.hpp:18,
                 from /opt/local/include/boost/config.hpp:40,
                 from step_by_step.cpp:7:
/usr/include/i386/_types.h:37: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘typedef’
make: *** [step_by_step] Error 1
```

Here are the details about the compiler

> Using built-in specs.
>   Target: i686-apple-darwin11
>   Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.1~22/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.1~22/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
>   Thread model: posix
>   gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)

Please help me compile it.

Thanks

Comment: That was a stupid mistake while copying the code from boost website. I've corrected that issue and it works well now.

Answer (score 0):

Not meant to be a solution, but I just tried this with the Boost release branch (what will be 1.49 soon), and it worked just fine.
And with the 1.47 release. (I don't have 1.48 installed)

Same compiler.

Comment: This should probably be a comment.